# Error building maven multi module project with frontend-maven-plugin

Tags: java, angular, maven, frontend

I am following [this](https://dzone.com/articles/building-a-web-app-using-spring-boot-angular-6-and) tutorial to build a project with Spring Boot backend and Angular frontend.

The only changes I made are the versions in the web project .pom:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v10.14.1</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>6.8.0</npmVersion>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/web/</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
...
```

The error I got is this:

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for dnd-mm 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] dnd-mm ............................................. SUCCESS [  1.188 s]
[INFO] dnd-mm-core ........................................ SUCCESS [ 10.483 s]
[INFO] dnd-mm-web ......................................... FAILURE [  1.735 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  14.077 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-27T12:09:10+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) on project dnd-mm-web: Execution inst
all node and npm of goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:install-node-and-npm failed: A required class was missing while executing com.github.ei
rslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:install-node-and-npm: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/1.7.5/frontend-maven-plugin-1.7.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/frontend-plugin-core/1.7.5/frontend-plugin-core-1.7.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.18/commons-compress-1.18.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.3/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar

[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.2/maven-plugin-annotations-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:install-node-and-npm (install nod
e and npm) on project dnd-mm-web: Execution install node and npm of goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:install-node-and-npm failed: A required
 class was missing while executing com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:install-node-and-npm: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/1.7.5/frontend-maven-plugin-1.7.5.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/frontend-plugin-core/1.7.5/frontend-plugin-core-1.7.5.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.18/commons-compress-1.18.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
urls[10] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar
urls[11] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
urls[12] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar
urls[13] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
urls[14] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.3/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.3.jar
urls[15] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[16] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.2/maven-plugin-annotations-3.2.jar
urls[17] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution install node and npm of goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:install-node
-and-npm failed: A required class was missing while executing com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:install-node-and-npm: org/codehaus/jackson/map/Obj
ectMapper
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/1.7.5/frontend-maven-plugin-1.7.5.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/frontend-plugin-core/1.7.5/frontend-plugin-core-1.7.5.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.18/commons-compress-1.18.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
urls[10] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar
urls[11] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
urls[12] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar
urls[13] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
urls[14] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.3/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.3.jar
urls[15] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[16] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.2/maven-plugin-annotations-3.2.jar
urls[17] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: A required class was missing while executing com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5:instal
l-node-and-npm: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.7.5
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/1.7.5/frontend-maven-plugin-1.7.5.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/frontend-plugin-core/1.7.5/frontend-plugin-core-1.7.5.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.18/commons-compress-1.18.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.3/commons-exec-1.3.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
urls[10] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar
urls[11] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
urls[12] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar
urls[13] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
urls[14] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.3/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.3.jar
urls[15] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[16] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.2/maven-plugin-annotations-3.2.jar
urls[17] = file:/C:/.../.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.7/plexus-build-api-0.0.7.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NPMInstaller.npmIsAlreadyInstalled (NPMInstaller.java:92)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NPMInstaller.install (NPMInstaller.java:81)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.InstallNodeAndNpmMojo.execute (InstallNodeAndNpmMojo.java:106)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute (AbstractFrontendMojo.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NPMInstaller.npmIsAlreadyInstalled (NPMInstaller.java:92)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.NPMInstaller.install (NPMInstaller.java:81)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.InstallNodeAndNpmMojo.execute (InstallNodeAndNpmMojo.java:106)
    at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute (AbstractFrontendMojo.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :dnd-mm-web
```

I have seen that this is a somewhat common error but I cannot find a solution that works for me.

I've tried changing the maven version (used: 3.0.4 but 3.1 and above was needed, 3.2.5, 3.3.3 bundled with IntelliJ and latest 3.6.0)

I messed around with the frontend-maven-plugin version using 1.3, 1.6, 1.7.5.

I added jackson-mapper-asl and jackson-core-asl 1.9.13 dependencies on the project, still nothing.

I was deleting .m2\repository\com\github folder throughout the above changes.

Nothing worked so far.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the frontend-maven-plugin itself.

I managed to run my code by executing the following steps:

1. I cloned the master branch from their github repository to my machine.
2. There is an import error in the NPMInstaller.java class file.
   I replaced the

   import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

with

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

and added the dependency in the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

3. I tried to build it but got some problems with maven-javadoc-plugin so I commented every entry I found in the project poms.
4. mvn clean install the root project. This created a 1.7.6-SNAPSHOT folder in my .m2 directory.
5. Altered the plugin version in my project to 1.7.6-SNAPSHOT and everything works fine.